# Devilbox Auto DNS on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, dns

I started using devilbox (https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox) which gives me a great and really easy to setup LAMP server.

Following the [docs for Windows Auto DNS](https://devilbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/dns/add-custom-dns-server-on-win.html#howto-add-custom-dns-server-on-win), you should make 127.0.0.1 your default DNS of your "active network adapter". However:

1. Setting DNS in my Wireless Adapter works but leads to losing Internet Access when docker/devilbox isn't running (as the DNS Server isn't running at this point)
2. Setting it on vEthernet Adapter (Hyber-v Virtual Ethernet adapter, probably created by Docker) works too but resets itself upon restarting
3. Setting it within Docker > Dashbord > Settings has no effect at all (probably because it is only for within docker and not on the
   host)

I can eighter set the alternate DNS in Solution 1 to e.g. 8.8.8.8 OR I have to edit DNS the vEthternet everytime I start devilbox. I therefore highly suspect that I'm missing something, and as the official docs are *thin* on this topic:

How can I setup Devilboxes DNS for Windows permanently?